# Heroku deploy using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: heroku, bitbucket

I am trying to use the Bitbucket Pipelines feature to deploy a node.js project to Heroku. The script(taken from documentation) is:

```
image: node:6
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install
          - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master
```

I have set up the enviorment variables for the API key and project name however I am getting the following error:

```
+ git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in .git
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out when I copied the app_name environment variable I copied it with a trailing space which was the error.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but in my experience so far the token expires every 8 hours so you'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore